# CakePHP 3.x mapReduce not working for querying multiple records

Tags: cakephp, mapreduce, cakephp-3.0

I have a database with `Course`, `Subject`, and `Chapter` table for CakePHP 3.x. The relation  between them as follows:

```
Courses        belongsToMany  Subjects
Courses        belongToMany   Chapters

Subjects       belongToMany   Courses
Subjects       hasMany        Chapters
Subjects       hasMany        ChildSubjects
Subjects       belongsTo      ParentSubjects

Chapters       belongToMany   Courses
Chapters       belongTo       Subjects
```

I need to retrieve all `Courses` with containing `Subjects`, `Subjects.ChildSubjects`, `Subjects.Chapters` and `Subjects.ChildSubjects.Chapters` which have the same course. I developed a custom finder with a `mapReduce`, which remove / unset / modify all those contains and also there associated contains, which are not the same course. It’s work fine when single course returns by course query. But, when it returned multiple courses, then `Subjects.ChildSubjects` and `Subjects.ChildSubjects.Chapters` are not returned properly.

I found the reason from Cookbook, `mapReduce()` method is a way of processing results once they are fetched from the database. That’s why, when I remove / unset / modifying result for one course, then it also affected by another course later.

How can I solve / skip that problem in my case? Is `formatResults` will be the best approach in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem finally. ***`mapReduce()` method is a way of processing results once they are fetched from the database whereas, `formatResults()` method is way of processing resultsets once they are decorated from fetched results.***

When I converted my `mapReduce` to `formatResults` then it works fine. My `mapReduce` was like as below:

```
$mapper = function ($course, $key, $mapReduce) {
    // start of mapper logic
    ... ... ... ... ... ...
    ... ... ... ... ... ...
    ... ... ... ... ... ...
    // end of mapper logic

    $mapReduce->emit($course, $key);
};

$query->mapReduce($mapper);
```

I changed it to `formatResults` like below:

```
//$query->mapReduce($mapper);

$query->formatResults(function ($courses) {
    return $courses->map(function ($course) {
        // start of mapper logic
        ... ... ... ... ... ...
        ... ... ... ... ... ...
        ... ... ... ... ... ...
        // end of mapper logic

        return $course;
    });
});
```